# Django | MultiValueDictKeyError at /users/user_newPassword/pDnxGRMutFpDUaF 'token'

Tags: python, django

Al realizar el post del formulario de crear nueva contraseña, el "def post" debería hacer por guardar la nueva contraseña, pero devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views.py:**

```
class CreateNewPasswordView(View):
    template_name = "users/crear_password.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')

    def get(self, request, token):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})

    def post(self, request, token):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            password1 = request.POST['password1']
            password2 = request.POST['password2']
            token = request.POST['token']
            if password1 == password2:
                u = User.objects.get(token=token)
                print(u.username)
                u.password=password1
                u.save()
                messages.success(request, 'La nueva contraseña ha sido creada con éxito. Ya puedes iniciar sesión con la nueva contraseña')
                template_name2 = "users/login.html"
                return render(request, self.template_name2, {})
            else:
                messages.success(request, 'Las contraseñas deben coincidir. Prueba de nuevo.')
                return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

Comment: Ahora el error es que estás intentando tomar `token` del diccionario `POST`, cuando ya lo estás recibiendo como argumento. Recuerda que `token` no es enviado dentro de la POST data, sino que es enviado como parte de la URL (o sea, algo tipo `'new-password/<token>'`). En pocas palabras: quita eso de `token = request.POST['token']`.

Comment: Gracias revliscanos. Efectivamente tras quitar ese token, ya no me sale ese error. Muchasa gracias.